# How is web page changing within the same website done?

Tags: html, web

For example, let's say we're at the homepage at www.fakewebsite.com and, when we look at the footer at the bottom of the page, we can see that there is an "About" button that you can click on--which you do so you get to know more about the company. The website refreshes and enters into www.fakewebsite.com/about. My question is this: How is this done? I'm pretty new to the web developing world and would like to know what is done to make this possible (So, I can do it too).

Comment: hope you find useful http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/text/http-tut.html

Comment: Google about: AJAX + History API.

Comment: Gahd. We are not google. Jon Skeet *is* (Google just being the proxy), but can't you bring your questions to him first? You have made no effort.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is known as an anchor and does not require ajax. You should start by searching info on that.

It looks like this:

```
<a href="about">about</a>
```

Comment: Oh, so you have to make separate html/css/etc. for different pages?

Comment: you can service multiple html pages with a single css file if you wish, just include a line like `<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>` in the head of each html page

Comment: You could look up some html-examples to get inspired: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_examples.asp

Answer (score 1):

This is done via an anchor element where the files are linked via a path in the `href` of the tag for example:

```
<a href="www.example.com/about">About</a>
```

More info here: [anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

You can also study this [starting with HTML + CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html) and this [Getting started with HTML](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Guide/)

Comment: Oh, so you have to make separate html/css/etc. for different pages?

Comment: If you want them to have different styles yes. However if they share common styling characteristics you can create only one css file and link it to all in the `<head></head>` section. About html though, you'll need a separate file.